# sharepoint designer 2010 workflow: to send an email in a certain date

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to create a workflow with SharePoint Designer 2010.

In a list, there is a date field and I need to send an email the day after that date.
For example, the item in the list has Nov 1 2014, and I need to send the email on Nov 2 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're new.  Sometimes people want a more descriptive question to assist.  Here are some online resources that will help you on your SP journey:

Video training, including workflow:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262880(v=office.14).aspx

Huge library of free Microsoft ebooks:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mssmallbiz/archive/2014/07/07/largest-collection-of-free-microsoft-ebooks-ever-including-windows-8-1-windows-8-windows-7-office-2013-office-365-office-2010-sharepoint-2013-dynamics-crm-powershell-exchange-server-lync-2013-system-center-azure-cloud-sql.aspx

SharePoint Conference videos:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Sharepoint-2010-Firestarter/SharePoint-2010-Firestarter
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2012
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014